# the correct translation of "attendu que"

Tags: terminology, legalese

does attendu que mean "given that" /"considering that"/ whereas. it appears at the beginning of every paragraph in a french legal document i'm working on and i'm not sure if all of the "attendu que"s mean "given that"( my best option) or any of the other options i listed

Comment: In English legalese, you'll often see series of paragraphs starting with *WHEREAS* (all capital letters). That's all I can offer, unfortunately, not being a lawyer.

Comment: In English, what a term means in ordinary language is not necessarily the same as what it means in a legal document. If the same is true in French, you may need to consult a French lawyer. There is this [*définition*](http://www.dictionnaire-juridique.com/definition/attendu-que.php) I found in *un dictionnaire juridique*, which may help.

Comment: @peter shor.. i guess thats what i might have to do.

Comment: Did you read the definition I found? Legal language in French is even more contorted than legal language in English! Summarizing: every judgement must consist of a single sentence (the grammar kind, not the legal kind), the subject being *"The Court"*, and having only one full stop on the end. The phrase *"Attendue que"* (starting with a capital *"A"*) introduces a subordinate clause giving a reason for the judgment.

Comment: @peter shor , yes i did. i strongly believe its "given that" because it is mostely used in legal documents and in courts. im not just very sure but im googling this in quotes.

Comment: I think it's more in the vein of "*considering that*" rather than "*given that*"

Comment: If it is Quebec or France, they do not have a common law system, so the form of a court opinion will be different from most Anglophone court opinions. Looking at a French-English-German law dictionary, I found the term rendered as *considering that; in consideration of; whereas*

Answer (score 1):

In a court order, just before the paragraph specifying the judgment or order is a paragraph listing the reasons for the order.  These reasons are called *findings of fact*. The paragraph would be laid out like this:

### Findings of Fact

The Court makes the following Findings of Fact:

1. That M and F were married 24 November 2003.
2. That M and F separated on 1 January 2007.
3. That three children were born of the marriage, to wit, X, Y, and Z,

*That* in the above sentence fragments is used in the same way as *attendu qu*.

You really need a French legal dictionary and an English legal dictionary to solve these problems, along with a working knowledge of *pleading*s, that is, customary legal forms.